# Can I change a user's nickname based on their ID?

Tags: java, discord-jda

Is it possible to change a user's nickname using their ID? I tried for a long time to solve this problem, but I never succeeded.

Comment: _I tried for a long time to solve this problem_ In which way? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Member#modifyNickname`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Member.html#modifyNickname(java.lang.String))?

```
Member member = event.getMember();
member.modifyNickname("Im a Maniac").queue();
```

Since you haven't provided code I can't tell if this snippet would work, it should if you refactor it as to your needs.

Comment: the thing is, I didn't come up with anything like an event.get Member().getJDA().getuserById(id);

Comment: I need to be able to change user's Nickname by user ID how to do it?

Comment: You will require the users ID, or an event fired by the member. Provide some code in order for me to help you more